# HTML5 Audio IsBuffering?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Is there any way to tell a song is buffering?

Events fire the first time when I hit play and song goes to play, I get the events but once the song is playing if the data is not coming in fast enough then it "pauses" but no events fire.

I've tried:

```
audioElement.addEventListener('suspend',function (){
    console.log('suspended'); //Fires the first time song is being "buffered"
});

audioElement.addEventListener('playing',function (){
    console.log('playing'); //Fires the first time the song is played.
});
```

How do I go about checking if the data is being buffered so that I can indicate to the user with some indication to wait?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your targeted browser and its implementation of the current W3C Working Draft HTML5 specification, Media Elements section.

You can always check if the browser you are targeting supports certain events here: http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html

Otherwise, if data is not coming through, then, I believe the audio won't be buffering and the `stalled` event will fire.

If data is coming through, then you should be able to check the `suspend` or `progress` events, both of which should fire whenever data is being buffered (but not necessarily paused/playing).

If these events are not firing because the browser isn't supporting them, you could always check the `networkState` attribute of the audio element using a timer, which essentially tells you if the audio is buffering or not:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <audio controls="controls" id="myAudio">
            <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html5/horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
            Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var audioElement = document.getElementById('myAudio');

var checkNetworkStateTimer = setInterval(function () {
    console.log(audioElement.networkState); //2 indicates NETWORK_LOADING state
}, 250);
```

Also on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3sdhj/2/

You probably won't be able to reproduce a `networkState` of `2` as the audio is too short a sample on jsFiddle but you get the idea.

If it still fails, I would go with a popular HTML5 audio library such as `SoundJS`, `Buzz` or `soundmanager2` (I am in no way affiliated with these libraries).

Comment: As a note this website is particularly useful: http://www.longtailvideo.com/html5/buffering

The libraries are unable to help.

Comment: @Omar Mir I didn't spot that website, good find for cross browser support.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the way the various vendors have set it up I cannot use anything to show my user the audio is buffering. I will show them a progress bar with the amount of buffered as a percentage. All I can do.